# Web component <google-map> not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, web-component

I am working on an app for Rails 4. I installed [this gem](https://github.com/alchapone/polymer-rails) to work with web components

At some point, I wanted to add [this component](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-map) to use Google Maps, so I installed it with bower

```
 ...
  "dependencies": {
    "google-map": "GoogleWebComponents/google-map#~1.0.3"
  }
 ...
```

and added it to my component list on app/assets/components/application.html

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.html, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any web component HTML file within this directory or vendor/assets/components, if any,
// can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
//= require polymer/polymer
//= require google-map/google-map
```

so I added the code to my website quite simply

```
    <style>
      google-map {
        height: 600px;
      }
    </style>

    <google-map latitude="37.77493" longitude="-122.41942"></google-map>
```

But all I get is whitespace. When I open the developer tools, I get this info:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_notifyEffect' of undefined
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_importsLoaded' of undefined

I know the element works, because if I try to use it in a vanilla website without framework, it works alright. What did I mess?

Comment: I get the same error messages when using `google-analytics-chart` in Meteor with Polymer 1.0.7. Wonder if it's the same issue causing these...

Comment: I figured out what my issue was. It is related to loading webcomponents.js incorrently. In my case I was loading it twice. Once in the regular way, and the second time because I was referencing my `google-analytics-chart` import incorrectly which was loading the app layout again (with a 404 message inside). So it might help to check the references to your HTML imports if they are corrent, otherwise check if webcomponents.js is loading twice (for example by editing the file and adding `console.log` at the beginning and end)